# How to add conditionally annotations on jpa entity hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, internationalization

Have a situation where I need to use single JPA Entity class for different databases.
I have used `@Nationalized` annotation on fields to support I18N. I need this `@Nationalized` annotation applicable only when I use oracle as my database. If I use same code for other databases it should not be consider(eg: derby)

is there any mechanism to achieve this in hibernate

Comment: To map your entities to multiple databases, you can use XML mappings or build your mappings in code.

Comment: Thanks @BrianVosburgh. You mean creating different mappings files for Oracle database

Comment: I have not done anything like this in years; but there should be a way to configure multiple `EntityManager`s to connect to different databases and use different `orm.xml` files that map your entities to the different databases. You can either have a different `orm.xml` for each database or you can use annotations for one database and configure the `orm.xml` files for the other databases to _override_ the annotations. There is more information in the JPA spec and elsewhere on the 'net.